# Where is the safari extension enabled/disabled state is found on mac os x?

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, osx-yosemite, safari-extension

secutiry find-generic-password -ga Safari 
command gives some string which is not in readable format. How can we know the extension state from the output of the above command?

Answer (score 2):

Safari extensions have nothing to do with "`security find-generic-password`" command.

There are two easy ways to determine your Safari extension enabled & disabled state:

1)

Go to the Safari Preferences and click on the "Extensions" tab.

You can see there which extensions are installed and enabled or disabled.

2)

In the command line, you can do something like this:

```
defaults read ~/Library/Safari/Extensions/extensions
```

And that dumps out a bunch of information, including whether the extension is "`Enabled`" or not.  More information can be found in the answers to this [apple.stackexchange.com question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/39240/list-the-extensions-installed-in-safari-for-mac-os-x-and-state-whether-each-one).

Answer (score 0):

It gives you a binary plist. Try to save it as foo.plist.

Comment: 'secutiry find-generic-password -ga Safari ' returns a bunch of information in 'data' field, but how do I save and open it?